# lua: how do I make getmetatable() return nil?

Tags: lua, overriding, metatable

I create a userobject in C, and as part of this I create a metatable to override methods like `__tostring`, `__index`, etc.  I noticed, though, that it's possible to retrieve the object's metatable through `getmetatable()`.  It seems that it's possible to make `getmetatable()` return any arbitrary table, if my metatable has a `__metatable` key.  I'd like `getmetatable()` to return `nil`, so my first thought was to add a `__metatable` key with `nil`, but that obviously doesn't work as it doesn't actually add the `__metatable` key to the metatable:

```
struct my_obj* obj = (struct my_obj*)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(struct my_obj));
if (luaL_newmetatable(L, "mymetatable") != 0) {
    lua_pushliteral(L, "__metatable");
    lua_pushnil(L);
    lua_rawset(L, -3); /* will not work, can not add a nil... */
}
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

Can this be done somehow, or do I have to stick with stuffing an empty table into `__metatable`?

Comment: Would `{ __metatable = false }` be close enough?

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `getmetatable` to return nil if the table has a `__metatable` key.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I don't see any way of getting this to work in lua (5.1, 5.2 or 5.3) given a quick look at the manual and code involved.

I'd wondered if there were some `__call`/etc. games you could play to make this work but the lookups are raw and don't do much checking beyond "is nil".